# how to keep drop down selected values after pressing submit button in php?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCjwo.jpg)I am using a dropdown list to show values in data tables. it's working but after press search button the dropdwon list clears.

```
<select name="staff" required>
    <option value="">Select Staff</option>
    <?php
        $query_subject = mysql_query("SELECT * from staffdet");

            while($row_subject = mysql_fetch_array($query_subject)) {
            ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_subject['staff_code'];?>"><?php echo $row_subject['staff_code']."-".$row_subject['staff_name'];?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

How to keep selected dropdown list values?

Comment: are you rerouting it to other page>

Comment: no . same page only.

Comment: can post your controller code

Comment: i am using normal php not an php codeigniter

Comment: okay but can you post your whole code

Comment: Explain a little bit more or post an screenshot

Answer (score 0):

IF you are submitting a form on same page with POST method then below code will solve your problem

```
<select name="staff" required>
<option value="">Select Staff</option>
<?php
    $query_subject = mysql_query("SELECT * from staffdet");

        while($row_subject = mysql_fetch_array($query_subject)) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_subject['staff_code'];?>" <?php if(!empty($_POST['staff']) && $_POST['staff']==$row_subject['staff_code']){echo 'selected="selected"';}?>>
            <?php echo $row_subject['staff_code']."-".$row_subject['staff_name'];?>
         </option>
<?php } ?>
```